# Как сравнить сгенерированное число с введенным числом в EditText?

Tags: java, android

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText SmsReg;
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 127;
    public Random random = new Random();
    private int random1 = Integer.valueOf(random.nextInt(8999) + 1000);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_layout);
        SmsReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSms);
        nm = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public void showNotification(View view) {    
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mill96)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.tttttt))
                .setTicker("Строго секретно")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("SMS Code")
                .setContentText("Code : " + random1);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    public void NextActivity(View view) {
        if (SmsReg.getText().equals(random1)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Converter.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

В частности, интересует вот эта строка:

```
if (SmsReg.getText().equals(random1))
```

**Обновление**

Создал переменную

```
final String str1 = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(8999) + 1000);
```

Сравнил

```
if (SmsReg.getText().toString().equals(str1))
```

Верно

Comment: И что в этой строке именно вас интересует?

Comment: А оно не работает? Пока не увидел последнюю строку, то в голове тоже самое было.

Comment: Выводит Toast(Не верно) Нужно указать что это числовой тип. Был бы буквенный, использовал toString

Comment: @Imperator, Преобразование числа в строку - `String.valueOf(random1)`. Но в данном случае всё равно работать не будет, скорее всего.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (SmsReg.getText().equals(random1))
```

Вы сравниваете `String` и `int`. Они никогда не равны в смысле `Object.equals()`.

Можно, например, конвертировать int в строку.

```
if (SmsReg.getText().equals(random1 + ""))
```

Если есть шанс, что `SmsReg.getText()` вернет `null`, то лучше так:

```
if ((random1 + "").equals(SmsReg.getText())
```

Comment: На самом деле, шанса нет. TextView и EditText никогда не возвращает null

Comment: @lsillarionov: хорошо, я просто не знаком с этими классами. В остальном ошибок не находите?

Comment: Ещё EditText.getText() возвращает CharSequence, а не String. Это может быть, например Editable с навешанными на текст span'ами (обычно так и есть), equals() которого вернет false. Это, по сути, то же самое сравнение разных типов. Нужно и результат getText() преобразовывать в строку. Когда у меня возникают сомнения, я обычно использую TextUtils.equals()

Comment: @lsillarionov: если не трудно, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, мой ответ, или свой добавьте. Так и я что-то новое узнаю )